# WSL2 git clone/pull throwing 'fatal: : gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.'

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu-12.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

Trying to setup dev environment on new work pc. Decided to utilize WSL2 and windows terminal. When in wsl2 i'm trying to clone/pull from git repo and getting the following error:

```
fatal: gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function
```

I've already tried a few suggested fixes but to no avail. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Things i've already tried (among other things):

- updating wifi/ethernet drivers
- disconnecting from vpn
- turning off IPV6
- modifying serveral conf files
- changing nameservers

**Hardware**: Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2nd

Edit:

*git seems to be extremely inconsistent, sometimes it works sometimes it throws an error. I've tried git via HTTPS, as well as, SSH.. both seem to have inconsistencies.*

**also, please note:** *the previous machine was running wsl2 and git without issue.*